Populating N-ary Tree with Depth first then left to right constraint
I'm trying to implement a function that populates the n-ary tree with these top two priorities (in this order): 1. Insert at the maximum possible depth. 2. Insert from left to right, as such an example is a depth of 3 and 12 elements with n of 3 children in the image:

This is my attempt so far, I have already tried to populate up until the maximum possible depth but got me confused on how I could implement the left to right constraint
int Tree::insertcell(int data, int depth, int* done, int maxchild, TreeNode* node) {
    for(int i = 0; i < maxchild; i++){
        cout << "children: " << i << endl;
        if (node->children[i] == nullptr && depth > 0){
            node->children[i] = new TreeNode(data, maxchild); //insert new node with data
            if(i == maxchild - 1){
                (*done) = depth + 1;
            }
            this->size += 1;
            return 1;
        }
        else if(node->children[i] != nullptr && depth > 0){
            if ((*done) > 0){
                this->insertcell(data, depth - 1, done, maxchild, node);
                continue;
            }else{
                this->insertcell(data, depth - 1, done, maxchild, node->children[i]); // access
            }
            this->size += 1;
            return 1;
        }
        else if(node->children[i] == nullptr && depth == 0){
            node->children[i] = new TreeNode(data, maxchild);
            this->size += 1;
            if(i == maxchild - 1){
                (*done) += 1;
            }
            return 1;
        }
        
    }
    return 0


What is the invariant for the maximum possible depth?

First some remarks on your approach:

The function does not foresee to insert the very first node into the tree, in which case you would have to update the root instance field (or however you have named it).

It should not be necessary to pass maxchild as argument to this insert function. Instead this value should be determined at the time you create the tree instance, and it should then be a field of the tree instance.

I would drop the done parameter. This easily becomes messy. You can instead drill down as far as you can through the last child node at each level, and then on unwinding from recursion, find the spot where to insert the new node. Then you don't need this done parameter.
So to put it in a different way, I would suggest an "optimistic" approach, where you find the rightmost child node (not null), and use the recursive call to insert a new node in that subtree. Then check the return value of the recursive call to see if that worked. If so, there is nothing more to do than to return success (1) also. If not, check if there is still room for a new child, and if so put the new node there. If that is not possible either, that means that the subtree rooted by node is full. In that case return 0, so that the caller can do something alternative to their optimistic choice.

Similarly, the initial call of insertcell should not need the depth, nor the node argument, as the depth of the tree should be determined once, at the creation of the tree instance. And the first node to work with would be the root of the tree. I would suggest creating that top-level method on the tree class (which only needs data as argument), and another insert method on the node class (for the recursion).

When the node you are about to create is going to be a leaf node, you should not pass maxchild to the TreeNode constructor. Instead pass 0, so to indicate that this node will not have children.

You seem to be using C++, where you should drop C habits, and prefer using vectors over C-arrays. So children would better be a vector, which means you would just push nodes to it until you reach the maximum size (maxchild). This way you don't have to look for nullptr in an array.


I provide here a possible implementation:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class TreeNode {
private:
    int data;
    std::vector<TreeNode*> children;
    int maxchild;

public:
    TreeNode(int data, int maxchild) : data(data), maxchild(maxchild) {}

    int insert(int data, int depth) {
        // Check if we have child nodes here
        int size = this->children.size();
        // If so, try to insert the new node in the last subtree
        if (size && this->children.back()->insert(data, depth - 1)) {
            return 1; // The new node was inserted in this i-th subtree
        }
        // The selected subtree is full.
        // Check if we can create a new child here:
        if (size == this->maxchild) {
            return 0; // Cannot add child here: backtrack
        }
        // Insert the new node here. Adapt maxchild argument according to depth
        this->children.push_back(new TreeNode(data, depth == 1 ? 0 : this->maxchild));
        return 1;
    }
    // Helper method to get some output
    std::string toString(std::string tab) {
        std::string s = tab + std::to_string(this->data) + "\n";
        for (auto child : this->children) {
            s += child->toString(tab + "  ");
        }
        return s;
    }
};

class Tree {
private:
    int size = 0;
    TreeNode* root = nullptr;
    int maxchild;
    int depth;

public:
    Tree(int maxchild, int depth) : maxchild(maxchild), depth(depth) {}

    int insert(int data) {
        if (!this->root) { // Empty tree? Insert the root...
            this->root = new TreeNode(data, this->depth == 0 ? 0 : this->maxchild);
            this->size = 1;
            return 1;
        }
        int success = this->root->insert(data, this->depth);
        this->size++;
        return success;
    }
    // Helper method to get some output
    std::string toString() {
        return this->root ? this->root->toString("") : "";
    }
};

Here is a demo run:
int main() {
    Tree* tree = new Tree(3, 3);
    for (int data = 0; data < 16; data++) {
        int success = tree->insert(data);
        if (!success) {
            std::cout << "could not add to tree";
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    std::cout << tree->toString();
}

This outputs a layman's view of the tree that was populated:
0
  1
    2
      3
      4
      5
    6
      7
      8
      9
    10
      11
      12
      13
  14
    15


Any feedback on this answer, @hakken?
